# How to create sub menu item within Docpad?

Tags: docpad

My document folder is structure like below

```
index.html
post/
  post1.html
  post2.html
pages/
  about.html
  interior.html
  exterior.html
  gallery.html
  post.html //listing blog post
  contact.html
  interior/
    in1.html
    in2.html
    ...
    in5.html
  exterior/
    ex1.html
    ex2.html
    ...
    ex7.html
  gallery/
    img1,2,3,4
```

My Menu structure like this

**Home | About us | Interior | Exterior | Gallery | Posts | Contact**

I create the menu by listing the page collection, it's Ok!

```
.navigation
nav
  ul.nav.topnav
    li.dropdown.active
      a(href='/')
        | Home
    each doc in getCollection('pages').toJSON()
      - clazz = (document.url === doc.url) ? 'active' : null
      li.dropdown(typeof="sioc:Page", about=doc.url, class=clazz)
        a(href=doc.url, property="dc:title")= doc.title
```

how can I add submenu item for Interior and Exterior by listing pages from interior/exterior folder

thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

May be you use [docpad-menu](https://github.com/sergeche/docpad-plugin-menu)..?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: hi npofopr, I use jade template, how to convert from eco to jade

Comment: Menu plugin seems to do it for me. Thanks npofopr. And I concur with @Sim's point of a more exacting answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This may be an inefficient way to handle this, but this is what I've figured out so far for something like this (CoffeeKup + Bootstrap):

```
  li class: "dropdown", ->
    a href: "#", class: "dropdown-toggle", "data-toggle": "dropdown", ->
      text "API"
      b class: "caret"
    ul class: "dropdown-menu", ->
      for file in @getFilesAtPath("api").toJSON()
        li ->
          if @document.relativeOutDirPath == "."
            a href: file.relativeOutPath, file.title
          else
            a href: "../" + file.relativeOutPath, file.title
```

Notice the `@getFilesAtPath("api").toJSON()` portion.  I have a folder called "/api" and it contains files.  Using this type of structure, the respective `<li>` tags for each file inside that folder.

Of course using this, you need to create another one of these things for each folder you create (I couldn't find a way to to loop through directory names).

The real garbage starts flying (and maybe you have a better attack at this), is the `<li>` tag itself.  Notice the if statement that needs to check to see if we are on the `index.html` page or some sub folder.  I then have to tack on the `"../"` to the file's path.  I've been searching but not yet have found a simple `@document.pathToRoot` style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could flag according docs in their respective YAML, e.g.

```
---
submenu: interior
title: in1
---
```

and use that to render from a matching collection in your nav or else like e.g.

```
<ul>
<% for entry in @getCollection("html").findAllLive({submenu: interior}).toJSON(): %>    
   <li><%= entry.title %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

To use the matching folder instead of YAML you'd change the query from `submenu: interior` to `relativeOutDirPath: /interior/`

Answer (score 0):

You could give your top level pages a meta-data tag `locationOfChildren` which would be the path to the folder where the child pages are.  If a top-level page (index.html for example) does not have children, then just don't define the tag or give it a value.

You then can add an if statement that will run a loop for the child document listing if `locationOfChildren` is defined.

```
.navigation
  nav
    ul.nav.topnav
      li.dropdown.active
        a(href='/')
          | Home
      each doc in getCollection('pages').toJSON()
        - clazz = (document.url === doc.url) ? 'active' : null
        li.dropdown(typeof="sioc:Page", about=doc.url, class=clazz)
          a(href=doc.url)= doc.title
          if doc.locationOfChildren
            ul.dropdown
              each childDoc in getFilesAtPath(doc.locationOfChildren).toJSON()
                - clazz = (document.url === childDoc.url) ? 'active' : null
                li.dropdown(typeof="sioc:Page", about=childDoc.url, class=clazz)
                  a(href=childDoc.url)= childDoc.title
```

You probably don't want your pages to be sorted alphabetically, so you can add a `navOrder` tag to the metadata of each page, and assign integer values to it.  In both of your query strings (getCollection and getFilesAtPath), add `.findAllLive({isPage:true},[{navigationOrder:1}])` before the `.toJSON()` method, and you should be good to go.

Ex:  `getFilesAtPath(doc.locationOfChildren).findAllLive({isPage:true},[{navOrder:1}]).toJSON()`